# How to achieve Tinder Style or stack based card swipe animation using xamarin forms across all platforms

Tags: xamarin.forms

After doing enough research, i could able to achieve it using Xamarin forms.

Android it was little tricky as it was not triggering **"GestureStatus.Completed"** in **OnPanUpdated** event when user does a swipe to certain area, but android triggers the Tap gesture event at this instance instead of Pan gesture event. So need to handle code separately for Android by collecting the coordinates of the card till where it was swiped.

Also to note for android, i have used a additional extra layout with opacity 0.0 upon the top card in the existing stack, with this we can get a smooth transition when user does the panning or swiping. Practically user swipes a extra layout with visible==true but with opacity 0.0, based on this extra transparent layout movements we will receive events in Tap or Pan gesture methods and we can move the actual top card in the existing stack which is under the transparent layout.

In *iPhone* and *Windows Phone* it triggers **GestureStatus.Running** and **GestureStatus.Completed** perfectly, so no need to create a hack extra layer.  Code snippet is pasted below.

Android sample code to achieve panning or swiping smoothly:
'

```
private AbsoluteLayout createGestureSupportlayout()
        {
            AbsoluteLayout gestureSupportlayout = new AbsoluteLayout();
            gestureSupportlayout.WidthRequest = frameWidth;
            gestureSupportlayout.HeightRequest = frameHeight;
            gestureSupportlayout.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
            gestureSupportlayout.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
            gestureSupportlayout.Opacity = 0.0;
            //In andriod, make Gesture support layout visible if invoices are present
            gestureSupportlayout.SetBinding(IsVisibleProperty, "GestureSupportLayoutVisible");
            return gestureSupportlayout;
        }
```

'

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin: [SwipeCardView](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MLToolkit.Forms.SwipeCardView/) is a lightweight MVVM friendly user control that brings Tinder-style swipe card view into Xamarin.Forms applications.

In your view xaml:

```xml
<swipeCardView:SwipeCardView
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelItems}"
                        SwipedLeftCommand="{Binding SwipedLeftCommand}"
                        SwipedRightCommand="{Binding SwipedRightCommand}"
                        TopItem="{Binding TopItem}">
   <swipeCardView:SwipeCardView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate x:Name="SomeTemplate">
     <!-- Template -->
       </DataTemplate>
   </swipeCardView:SwipeCardView.ItemTemplate>
</swipeCardView:SwipeCardView>
```

For a detailed explanation of design, implementation and usage of this library, check my blog post: [Create Tinder-like UI in Xamarin Forms using SwipeCardView.](https://markolazic.com/swipecardview-tinder-ui-xamarin-forms/)

Answer (score 0):

Another framework for this is https://github.com/robinmanuelthiel/swipecards